# how to fix pandas column name to show only columnname instead of tablename.columnname

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, hive

When I load the data in pandas, the column of the df show up as

`tablename.columnname1 | tablename.columnname2 | tablename.columnname3| ..... | tablename.columnnameN`

how do I make it only show as

`columnname1 | columnname2 | columnname3| ..... | columnnameN`

the data was processed on pyspark, originally retrieved from hive. when I show the df on pyspark, the column names show up normal without the table names in front of it.

after the process is done, it is written in a schema in hive again as schemaname.tablename

when I downloaded it to local and feed into pandas all column names show up as

tablename.columnname

I have about 1000 features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `rename` method in addition to `string.replace` to remove the string `"tablename."`

#### Making dummy data

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], columns=["tablename.col1", "tablename.col2", "tablename.col3"])

print(df)
   tablename.col1  tablename.col2  tablename.col3
0               1               2               3
1               4               5               6
```

Using the rename method

```
new_df = df.rename(columns=lambda name: name.replace("tablename.", ""))

print(new_df)
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     2     3
1     4     5     6
```